# 2D Perlin Noise Terrain Generator Error (Java)

Tags: java, git, perlin-noise

My name is Chris and first, I'd like to thank for you for taking time out of your day to look at this question.

And yes I am a beginner.
At the moment, I am trying to create a game along the lines (and with the same Terrain generation) as Minicraft (Yes, Mini, not Mine) by Notch. (Link Here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/ld22/index.html)

Anyway, I attempted to make my own using a YouTube tutorial, of course the YouTuber's worked perfectly and mine had more than a couple of errors.

The error is as follows:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at code.BlockImages.getBlockImages(BlockImages.java:8)
at code.Terrain.setid(Terrain.java:17)
at code.WorldGen.genWorld(WorldGen.java:8)
at code.GenLoader.create(GenLoader.java:12)
at code.Skeleton.init(Skeleton.java:14)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at code.BlockDirt.<clinit>(BlockDirt.java:8)
... 7 more
```

I put the source code (as its many files and this post would be very long) on Github, here:
https://github.com/KultidGames/Brandish/tree/master/Game_01/src/code

Thank you and goodbye

Comment: Hi Chris. In addition to the error above, there's an error in Loop.run(), where you're doing few rle = ImageIO.read(new File("Main Char Left Run.png")); Where are these files? (Main Char Left Run.png") etc - I don't see them in the project...

Comment: They're in the Images folder, I updated the code and but got the error:
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at code.Loop.run(Loop.java:29)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is happening on the initialization of the classes. It is probably because it is not finding one of the resources for the images.

From what I found [here](http://cpaul.is-programmer.com/posts/25131.html), it is probably the spaces in the names of the resources. Try either using that fix, or renaming the files to remove the space.